# SFDX push to playground/specific org

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, git

Hi Stack Exchange community, right now I'm learning to code with SF but I'm stuck with a very specific problem, I was trying to add LWCC (https://salesforcelabs.github.io/LightningWebChartJS/) to use it with lightning web components, following the steps to install it. It allows to use it in a scratch org, but I'm trying to install it in the playground.

How can I do this? I already did the cloning from git, so I have the code locally, I thought at first I just had to push but no success so far.

Any help is welcome, thanks c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the data to metada and then push it/deploy it to the playground solved the issue.

[Video that helped me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWp45OFUhzU&ab_channel=SFDCStop)

Answer (score 0):

You can't push or pull from non-tracked orgs (Scratch Orgs and [some Sandboxes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm)). Instead, use `force:source:deploy` to deploy the metadata to your org. Be aware that a deploy will overwrite any matching configuration in the playground, so some casual caution is advised.

Comment: Hey thank you, the solution in the end was converting the code to metadata and then push that to the playground.